# Highcharts Gantt Setting Dependency Type

Tags: javascript, highcharts, gantt-chart, highcharts-gantt

I'm setting up a highcharts gantt view and have successfully included tasks and dependencies in a working view `#woohoo!`

**I'm looking for a way to define the dependency relationship/type** and have highcharts represent the line connectors appropriately.  It seems highcharts gantt is pre-configured to for `end-to-start` relationships; however, my project has `end-to-end` dependencies and some `start-to-start` types as well.

Is there anyway to have highcharts render these dependency relationship types?

Here is an example of an end-to-end dependency on the **Customer Training** & **Plan & Foundation Build** tasks from the project management utility.
[image: End-to-end dependency example]

Here is how Highcharts is representing the same 4 tasks and relationship types - notice all dependency lines are `end-to-start` types:

[image]

Does anyone know of a an approach for this in highcharts gantt?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate the arrow position by `dependency.startMarker.align`:

```
series: [{
    dependency: {
      to: 'prepare_building',
      startMarker: {
        align: 'right',
        color: 'black'
      }
    },
    ...
  }, ...]
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/aycwz7u2/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/gantt/series.gantt.data.dependency.startMarker.align